# Run several javascript file dynamically using same npm run command

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

My folder structure:

```
app

  Model

    user.js
    post.js
```

My package.json file

```
"scripts": {
    "migrate": "node ./app/Model/"
}
```

I want to run javascript file in command line dynamically.

Like:

```
npm run migrate user.js
npm run migrate post.js
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a script that dynamically requires the decired js file.

```
"scripts": {
    "migrate": "node model.js"
}
```

Then `model.js` like this:

```
const path = require('path');    
require(path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'Model', process.argv[2]));
```

Comment: It's giving Error: Cannot find module 'E:\project\app\Model\C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe'

Comment: @ShivamChhetri I don't have node on my current machine. So i cant test it. But it looks like the first argument in `process.argv` is a ref to node. try `process.argv[1]` instead. And remember the `--`

Comment: It's working with process.argv[2] and there's no need of -- before user.js

Answer (score 0):

```
"scripts": {
"migration": "node Model.js"
```

}

```js
const program = require('commander');

program
    .command('f <file>')
    .description('Database migration.')
    .action(async (file) => {
        console.log(file);//do something here
    });


program.parse(process.argv);
```

> npm run migration f post.js